# Openerp MRP module: assigning employees to work orders

Tags: odoo

In the MRP module, I would like to assign different employees to the work orders of a manufacturing order, so I can tarck the amount of hours and the cost for every employee (beause they will have different service products with different costs) and create analytic  journal items based on this.

My question is: Is there any option or extra module for this or should I customize the MRP module?

Thanks in advance. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is from some time ago but I would like to know if you found and answer?

This is a long winded reply, but I am also needing this capability and searching any such existing module or planning develop this capability

Currently and soon to be completed is a new module with many enhancements to manufacturing order>>work order lines these include.

1. The ability to link a BOM component/consumed products to a routing work line on the BoM Component lines.
2. A constraint where by MFG Work Orders can only start when the component/consumed products assigned to them are available.  This gives ability to start individual work orders as there individual consumed component products become available and to stage multiple works orders from many manufacturing orders base on which products have been picked and  transfer to production.
3. The ability to define a constraint that previous  work orders in sequence must complete before a work order can start.
4. New statuses on work order that waiting for product, waiting for previous work and ready.
5. The ability to assign warehouse locations to routing work center lines and to generate Internal Pickings not just to a specific Manufacturing orders but also to Work center work orders so that pickings can be schedule to all the current jobs needing consumable products.

What I am also planning in phase 2 of this development are feature similar to your question

1. allowing to define group of employees link to Routing work center lines. many2many from routing work center to employees
2. adding to search view on the Work Orders List View for search and group by for assigned employee or employee group.
3. Add ability to assign an employee to a work order
4. If  logged in as other than the assigned employee Attempts to set work order to In Progress system will warn that they are not the assign employee for this work order. constraint can be overridden if user has manger permission he has choice to reassign work to himself or start work for the assigned employee.
5. Adding linkage to hr_timesheet so that time when work order is in progress is entered on employees time sheet.
6. Have logic that confirms employee is signed in on attendance or will automatically sign them in when a work order assigned to them is set to In Progress.
7. To have work order status set to paused automatically when assigned employees signs out in time sheet attendance.
8. to log time work was in progress on their Time sheet when work is set to pause or Finished

Regards
SL

Comment: where can I find the module that you are referring to, ( the one that you developed) ?